# a 3D modeling software runs slowly but my pc is fast: should I format or is it a hardware incompatibility?

Tags: installation, performance, formatting, compatibility, 3d-modeling

I have Windows 10 pro x64 on a high-performance assembled portable workingstation with the features below->

> Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
>
> Memory : 8088MB(1600)
>
> Mother Board : P170EM
>
> Windows Version : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
>
> Installation Date : 2016-11-14
>
> Monitor : Default Monitor
>
> Video Adapter : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M
>
> Mouse : PS/2 Compatible Mouse
>
> Keyboard : Standard PS/2 Keyboard
>
> Disk Drive : INTEL SSDSC2CW060A(55GB,IDE)
>
> DVD/CD-ROM Drive : Slimtype DVD A  DS8A8SH
>
> a second internal drive (har disk) installed, no raid

I have Windows installed on the 60 GB SSD.
I usually install programs in the second internal drive (hard disk).

---

Now I'm running 3d modelling softwares but I have troubles with Solidworks 2016 x64. **I run 3DsMAX 2017 x64 in the same pc and it works fine**, whereas Solidworks is very very slow; I tried installing Solidworks both in the SSD and in the hard disk without seeing any difference.
It runs faster on other portable computers **with weaker video cards**, see the following features->

---

ON ALIENWARE ------>

> model -> Alienware 13 R2
>
> Video cards ->  NVIDIA GEFORCE gtx 960 m  and Intel hd graphics 520
>
> intel core i7 6500U CPU 2.5 GHz@ 2.60 ghz
>
> 8 G ram
>
> bios 1.2.0
>
> Win 8.1 x64

---

The graphic card installed on Alienware is weaker than mine, according to the report below ->

---

[image: Graphic cards comparison]

---

---

ON ASUS ZEN ------>

---

> model -> asus zenbook ux301
>
> video card -> intel iris graphics 5100 (it seems it only has this
> graphics processor, I checked both in the device manager panel and with
> `dxdiag` tool, see also the screen below)
>
> CPU -> intel quad i7
>
> win 10
>
> two SSD , RAID

---

As you can see below, the videocard is really weaker than mine ->

---

[image: Asus video card]

[image: Asus videocard 2]

---

Moreover SOLIDWORKS runs faster in a Mac laptop with a less powerful CPU and even on others which don't have certified video cards (according to what my teacher said).
I set my NVIDIA control panel and told it to use the high performance NVIDIA processor while running Solidworks->

[image: NVIDIA control panel settings]

---

More specifically the settings for the program are the following ->

---

[image: NVIDIA control panel settings 2]

[image: NVIDIA control panel settings 3]

[image: NVIDIA control panel settings 4]

[image: NVIDIA control panel settings 5]

I disabled the applications which might create compatibility issues according to my experience (antivirus, antiramsomware, antimalwares, sandboxie).

I tried installing (and uninstalled) the software both in the SSD and in the hard disk (they are both internal) but I didn't solve the problem.

In other terms, there are no apparent reasons why my pc is so slow when I run Solidworks because it's a powerful workingstation; I tested the software on other -less powerful- laptops and it run faster. Solidworks is supposed to be fully compatible with Windows 10 AFAIK. I wonder if I should format my ssd and do a clean installation of Windows; but it's also true that my operating system is fast except than while running Solidworks.
I also use other heavy programs (e.g. Photoshop CS6 x64, 3DS Max...) and they are ok.

In the screens below you can see how the software acts in my system ->

[image: solidworks impact on the system]

[image]

---

and these are the running tasks ->

---

[image: running tasks]

---

My VGA benchmark below (see also [http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+GTX+675M](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce%20GTX%20675M) )  ->

---

[image]

I tested it with a benchmark tool (GPU burner) and I got the following ->

[image]

Graphic card driver are up-to-date (I checked with devID, downloaded from here-> http://devid.info/ : no mention of NVIDIA drivers in the report).
Anyhow I updatet all the drivers which DevID detected as out-of-date, restarted and loaded Solidworks again but nothing changed.

**Might it be possible that a software runs slowly because the operative system needs to be reinstalled, even when it seems to be completely ok while running all the other programs? Or might it depend on hardware incompatibility**?

p.s. I recently asked my teacher if the VGA might be the problem and he said that Solidworks runs on the graphic processor, so the video card doesn't matter: it sounds quite odd, may it be possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50076/discussion-on-question-by-robertalrp-a-3d-modeling-software-runs-slowly-but-my-p).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling Windows but I didn't choose the "format" option.

I reinstalled Windows 10 x64 from the same ISO on usb stick on the same partition (C:) and by using the same license.
In the installation menu I just selected which partition to use to install Windows, I didn't chose the "format" option, so I didn't format the partition properly but just let Windows installing itself and doing the job.

Once I had Windows again I installed Solidowrks and Bitdefender and launched Solidworks: it works fast now, so I may exclude any incompatibility with the Antivirus software installed.

Then I re-installed all the other programs and no one created incompatibility issues with Solidowrks so far, the program is keeping working very well.

I also checked and learnt that this 3Ds modelling software runs faster on weaker PCs, no need for a very powerful graphic card with x GB dedicated (except than when doing rendering, which may require higher hardware performances and in that case using a high performance Nvidia Quadro makes the difference).
So it runs very good even on a old-generation graphic card for gaming and slowness only depended on the operative system.